# Transfer Dukt Analytics to new build

Tags: plugins, analytics

I'm working on a new build of a site with a new database, I think that copying the plugin folder will not carry over the analytics statistics, are there database entries that I need to copy over?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but if it's a new site/database, why would you want analytics data for a different site?

Comment: Not a silly question, I meant a new build/site as in new database, same website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like Dukt Analytics has any tables it creates in the database, but it does require Dukt OAuth, which creates a `craft_oauth_providers` table and a `craft_oauth_tokens` table you could move over.

Both of the plugin save their plugin settings in the `craft_plugins` table, so you might want to move their rows over as well.